# aws-cli create-invalidation gives Signature expired error

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

My script involves uploading files to s3, and then creates an invalidation to refresh the contents.

The uploading to s3 part works fine, but when creating invalidation, I got this error:

```
An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the CreateInvalidation 
operation: Signature expired: 20190717T012747Z is now earlier than 
20190717T012755Z (20190717T013255Z - 5 min.)
```

However the s3 operations works, so it is a puzzle to me why cloudfront doesnt work.

My script is something like:

```
# deploy to the s3 bucket
aws s3 sync ./public/. s3://{bucket} --grants read=uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers
# invalidate CF
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id {dist_id} --paths /*
```

My IAM permission is set to `CloudFrontFullAccess`, which is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "acm:ListCertificates",
                "cloudfront:*",
                "iam:ListServerCertificates",
                "waf:ListWebACLs",
                "waf:GetWebACL"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: update your system date time and normally happen due to slow internet